I want to use a nested if(and) excel function on multiple conditions for 3 outcomes "Valid","Invalid" OR "" blank, how best can I write these?
=IF(
    AND(
        [@[Key Populations]]<>"Preg";
        [@[Key Populations]]<>"BF";
        [@Age]>14;
        P135>='information Sheet'!$AD$2;
        P135<='information Sheet'!$AE$2
        );
    "VALID";
    "INVALID";
    IF(
    (OR(
        [@[Key Populations]];"Preg";
        [@[Key Populations]];"BF";
        [@Age]=<14;
        P135>='information Sheet'!$AD$2;
        P135<='information Sheet'!$AE$2
        );
    " ";
    "False")))

I got error message, I expecting Valid, Invalid or blank

So if I'm following, you have blank/false for the second If, whereas you don't care about the false outcome, but the other if statement could be inserted.  That would be four possible outcomes... eliminate one by adding the second if statement as the outcome:
=IF(
    OR(                                     'Condition
        [@[Key Populations]];"Preg";
        [@[Key Populations]];"BF";
        [@Age]=<14;
        P135>='information Sheet'!$AD$2;
        P135<='information Sheet'!$AE$2
        );
    " ";                                    'True
    IF(                                     'False
    AND(
        [@[Key Populations]]<>"Preg";
        [@[Key Populations]]<>"BF";
        [@Age]>14;
        P135>='information Sheet'!$AD$2;
        P135<='information Sheet'!$AE$2
        );
    "VALID";
    "INVALID")))


Interpreting it slightly differently:

blank if age is blank or P135 is out of bounds
blank if key populations is an excluded value
set valid/invalid based on age

Please change absolute reference in $P$135 to P135, according to your need.
=IFS(
    OR(
        $P$135 < 'Information Sheet'!$AD$2,
        $P$135 > 'Information Sheet'!$AE$2,
        ISBLANK([@Age])
    ),
    "",
    OR([@[Key Populations]] = "Preg", [@[Key Populations]] = "BF"),
    "",
    [@Age] > 14,
    "VALID",
    TRUE,
    "INVALID"
)


